# Horizontal Scroll View gallery is limited 5 photo only

Tags: android, scrollview, gallery

I make application with android studio about horizontal scroll view gallery images only , I make 15 ImageView in my layout .application stopped when i add larger than **five images**

this is my code , please any help

```js
package ikh.ago.com.mall;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();


        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                //answer = "You are connected to network";
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), answer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                ImageView zarawomen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zarawomen) ;
                zarawomen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Massemo.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });

                ImageView massemo_women = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.massimoduttiwomen) ;
                massemo_women.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Massemo.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });


                ImageView mango = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mango) ;
                mango.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Massemo.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });


                ImageView pbstore = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pbstore) ;
                pbstore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Massemo.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });

                

                ImageView bershka2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bershka2) ;
                bershka2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Massemo.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });


                ImageView gap = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gap) ;
                gap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Massemo.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });


                ImageView massemo_men = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.massimoduttimen) ;
                massemo_men.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Massemo.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });


                ImageView pb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pb) ;
                pb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Massemo.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });

                ImageView zaraman = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zaraman) ;
                zaraman.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Massemo.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });

                ImageView cafehello = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cafehello) ;
                cafehello.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Massemo.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });

                ImageView costa = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.costa) ;
                costa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Massemo.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });

                ImageView compume = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.compume) ;
                compume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Massemo.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });

                ImageView englander = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.englander) ;
                englander.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Massemo.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });

                ImageView casio = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.casio) ;
                casio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Massemo.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });


            } else {
                //answer = "No Network Connectivity";
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), answer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ImageView zarawomen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zarawomen) ;
                zarawomen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                ImageView massemo_women = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.massimoduttiwomen) ;
                massemo_women.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                ImageView mango = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mango) ;
                mango.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                ImageView pbstore = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pbstore) ;
                pbstore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                ImageView bershka2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bershka2) ;
                bershka2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                ImageView gap = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gap) ;
                gap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                ImageView massemo_men = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.massimoduttimen) ;
                massemo_men.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                ImageView pb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pb) ;
                pb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                ImageView zaraman = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zaraman) ;
                zaraman.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                ImageView cafehello = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cafehello) ;
                cafehello.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                ImageView costa = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.costa) ;
                costa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                ImageView compume = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.compume) ;
                compume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                ImageView englander = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.englander) ;
                englander.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                ImageView casio = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.casio) ;
                casio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
     }

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    }
    



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ikh.ago.com.mall.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:background="#000000">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="always">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/mygallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/zarawomen"
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="393dp"
                android:src="@drawable/zarawomen" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="393dp"
                android:id="@+id/massimoduttiwomen"
                android:src="@drawable/massimoduttiwomen" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="393dp"
                android:id="@+id/mango"
                android:src="@drawable/mango" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="393dp"
                android:id="@+id/pbstore"
                android:src="@drawable/pbstore" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="393dp"
                android:id="@+id/bershka2"
                android:src="@drawable/bershka2" />



            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="393dp"
                android:id="@+id/gap"
                android:src="@drawable/gap" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="393dp"
                android:id="@+id/massimoduttimen"
                android:src="@drawable/massimoduttimen" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="393dp"
                android:id="@+id/pb"
                android:src="@drawable/pb" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="393dp"
                android:id="@+id/zaraman"
                android:src="@drawable/zaraman" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="393dp"
                android:id="@+id/cafehello"
                android:src="@drawable/cafehello" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="393dp"
                android:id="@+id/costa"
                android:src="@drawable/costa" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="393dp"
                android:id="@+id/compume"
                android:src="@drawable/compume" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="393dp"
                android:id="@+id/englander"
                android:src="@drawable/englander" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="393dp"
                android:id="@+id/casio"
                android:src="@drawable/casio" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`. http://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the exception message when your app is stopped?, I think that is for a memory consuming, try to put android:largeHeap="true" in the Application Tag from your manifest.xml.

Additionally I think that is better implementation if you do a RecyclerView with a Horizontal LayoutManager, with this form you prevent create 15 ImageView because the RecyclerView reuse your xml resource.
RecyclerView Adapter uses ViewHolder Pattern, Maybe can help you in this case.

[How to use a RecyclerView](http://androhub.com/android-staggered-and-horizontal-recyclerview/)